# How can I add a Class Object to an Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following situation in PHP

```
class MyObject{
    var $myVar;
    function setMyVar($tVar){ $this->myVar = $tVar; }
    function getMyVar(){ return $this->myVar; }
}

class ObjectHandler{

    function createAnArray(){
        $mObject = new MyObject();
        $arrayOfObject = array(); 

        $mObject->setMyVar("anyString");

        $arrayOfObject = mObject;

        return $arrayOfObject;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the array I can't find any object of the MyObject class. In Java it works fine. How do I do it in PHP?

Comment: I guess, you will have to actually **learn** basics of PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are setting `$arrayOfObject` to be the actual object. Assuming you want to stick your object *inside* the array, change:

```
$arrayOfObject = mObject;
```

To:

```
$arrayOfObject[] = $mObject; // Note the $ before $mObject here as well
```

This will *add* the object as an element in your array, rather than overwrite the entire array variable. You will find your object now at `$arrayOfObject[0]`.

Comment: You should explicitly say that he's missing the `$` also.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ObjectHandler{

    function createAnArray(){
        $mObject = new MyObject();
        $arrayOfObject = array(); 

        $mObject->setMyVar("anyString");

        $arrayOfObject[] = mObject;     //that means  $arrayOfObject[0] =mObject;

        $mObject2 = new MyObject();
        $arrayOfObject[] = mObject2;     //that means  $arrayOfObject[1] =mObject2;

        return $arrayOfObject;
    }
```